# We are they who lock the heart

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, video-games

> Seven lights that guard the key of hearts,
> They alone can stop what the dark starts,
>
> The first is king and friend,
> With three circles he was penned.
>
> The second not chosen by man,
> But destiny had another plan.
>
> The third fell, it was true,
> But returned to those he knew.
>
> The fourth was split until he break,
> He heals in a heart until he wakes.
>
> The fifth travels in darkness,
> She fights against the heartless.
>
> The sixth caught in his own dark desires,
> His body controlled by He who conspires.
>
> The seventh, unknown, but possibly she,
> Who is seventh of light, set free.

Who are we?

Comment: Is there a reason why this was down voted? For future references, I'd like to know what to avoid.

Comment: This feels more like a trivia question than a puzzle; you either know the answer, in which case it is relatively straightforward, or you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> The *Seven Guardians of Light* from the [Kingdom Hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts) universe.

The first is king and friend, With three circles he was penned.

> King Mickey Mouse of Disney castle. The three circles are the famous silhouette of his face and ears.

The second not chosen by man, But destiny had another plan.

> Sora, who was chosen by the "Keyblade."

The third fell, it was true, But returned to those he knew.

> Riku. He disappeared into the darkness and separated from his friends. He was later reunited with Sora in Traverse Town.

The fourth was split until he break, He heals in a heart until he wakes.

> Ventus. He lost his heart and went into a coma. His heart healed inside Sora until it returned to him and he woke.

The fifth travels in darkness, She fights against the heartless.

> Aqua. She cast herself into the realm of darkness.

The sixth caught in his own dark desires, His body controlled by He who conspires.

> Terra, who has darkness in his heart but refuses to accept it. Master Xehanort possessed his body.

The seventh, unknown, but possibly she,
Who is seventh of light, set free.

> The seventh Guardian of Light has yet to be identified in the saga, however many believe it is *Kairi*.

Comment: The answer is correct, though I would have liked it answered line by line with a brief explanation on each line.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Ok edited, hope I got them all right.

Comment: Excellent edit, answers everything that I was looking for.